# Best approach to pass data from web view to native app (Windows, iOS & Android)

Tags: android, ios, windows-8, webview

Wondering what the best approach is to read HTML/JS within a webview in a native app that works for:

- **iOS**
- **Android**
- **Windows Phone**

Can all three platforms read the content of a web view, or does the sandbox prevent that from happening?

Comment: Please have a look for iOS

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537320/invoke-method-in-objective-c-code-from-html-code-using-uiwebview/15541607#15541607

Comment: Thanks - really helpful. I'm still checking if this works on Windows Phone 8 platform and will share anything that I find.

Comment: El-codino what did you find?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**iOS:**

[More Details](http://www.handcraftedsoftware.net/articles/how-to-pass-messages-between-native-ios-and-a-uiwebview-via-ajax-without-phonegap)

[passing-data-to-and-from-an-embedded-uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117713/passing-data-to-and-from-an-embedded-uiwebview)

[ios-pass-values-to-native-app-from](http://davehiren.blogspot.in/2012/10/ios-pass-values-to-native-app-from.html)

[image]

**Android:**

[webkit-communication-with-native-environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257106/webkit-communication-with-native-environment)

Comment: The first link is dead. FYI.

Answer (score -1):

On iOS you can fairly easy communicate with web view injecting some JS. In opposite direction calling messages is a bit more complicated, but still possible, when you create a kind of bridge between JS and iOS.

I think on Android is probably easier. Don't know about Windows Phone.